# What does the word "mishkav" mean in Biblical Hebrew

Tags: hebrew, grammar, hermeneutical-approaches, homosexuality, bible

I do NOT mean "bed". But rather how it is being used in some specific verses:

Num. 31:17, 18, & 35; Jdgs.12:11 & 12; Ezk 23:17)

What does the word "mishkav" as mentioned ONLY in
Num. 31:17,18, & 35; Jdgs.21:11 & 12; Ezk 23:17 mean in Hebrew Scriptures translated to English? What grammatical & contextual explanation do you have for your answer?

In those verses, it can NOT mean "bed" in a literal sense.

- Num 31:17 - Now therefore, kill every male among the little ones, and kill every woman who has known man by **lying** with him.
- Judges 21:11 - And they found among the inhabitants of Jabesh-gilead 400 young virgins who had not known a man by **lying** with him, and they brought them to the camp at Shiloh, which is in the land of Canaan.
- Eze 23:17 - And the Babylonians came to her into the **bed** of love, and they defiled her with their whoring lust. And after she was defiled by them, she turned from them in disgust.

Answer (score 1):

The Hebrew word מִשְׁכָּב (mishkav) occurs 46 times in the OT always means either

- a bed for lying on
- the act of lying and as such, is a euphemism for sexual activity

In the three sets of texts quoted by the OP, the meaning is clearly the final - the act of lying on a bed as a euphemism/idiom for sexual activity.

Even in modern English, to say someone "bedded" someone else, or to say to "go to bed with someone" is still a euphemism for sexual activity.

**APPENDIX - BDB lexicon entry for מִשְׁכָּב**

> **1 couch, bed** (37 t.), 2 Samuel 4:11; Hosea 7:14; Micah 2:1; 1 Kings 1:47; Songs 3:1 +; ׳וְנָפַל לְמ Exodus 21:18 (E) he takes to his
> bed; נִדָּתָהּ ׳מ Leviticus 15:26 (P; see below I. נדד); ׳מ as place
> of copulation Genesis 49:4 (poem in J), Isaiah 57:7,8 (twice in
> verse); Proverbs 7:17; as place of burial Isaiah 57:2; Ezekiel 32:25;
> 2Chronicles 16:14 (see ׳מ Inscription Tabnit8 and perhaps Jewish
> inscription Cooke341).
>
> **2 act of lying:**
>
> a. in General, ׳חֲדַר מ chamber of lying down = bed-chamber, Exodus
> 7:28 (E), 2 Samuel 4:7; 2 Kings 6:12, בְּחַדְרֵי מִשְׁכָּֽבְךָ
> Ecclesiastes 10:20; הַצָּהֳרַיִם ׳והוּא שֹׁכֵב אֵת מ 2 Samuel 4:5 his
> noon-day siesta; 2 Samuel 17:28 read perhaps ׳עַרְשׂת מ couches for
> lying down Klo Bu HPS Now, compare ᵐ5.
>
> b. (from context) sexually: of woman יֹדַעַת (אִישׁ לְ) מִשְׁכַּב
> זָכָת Judges 21:11,12; Numbers 31:17,35 (P); of man שׁכב מִשְׁכְּבֵי
> אִשָּׁה Leviticus 18:22; Leviticus 20:13 (+ אֶתזָֿכָר sodomy; H);
> ׳דֹּדִים מ Ezekiel 23:17.